# Why can't I assign one iterator to another in C++?

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm writing this function

```
vector<string> SplitIntoWords(const string& s) {
    vector<string> v_str = {};
    string::iterator str_b;
    str_b = begin(s);

    // TODO some action here

    return v_str;
}
```

and I need to declare an iterator which will be equal to begin of the string s, which is a parameter in my function.

The problem is with the line `str_b = begin(s);` - the code doesn't compile with it. Why so and how can I fix it?

Comment: Need to `#include <iterator>`.   And for a `const string`, need to use `std::const_iterator` rather than `std::iterator`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`s` is *const* object, so

```
begin(s)
```

returns `string::const_iterator`, you cannot assign `string::const_iterator` to `string::iterator`. You can fix it by

```
string::const_iterator str_b;
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `s` is `const`-qualified, `begin(s)` returns a `string::const_iterator`:

```
string::const_iterator str_b;
str_b = begin(s);
```

or better, let `auto` deduce `str_b`'s type from its initializer:

```
auto str_b = begin(s);
```